# Значение (int)malloc

Tags: c, malloc, int

Правильно ли я понимаю.
Если мы выделяем память `void* a=malloc(100)` то мы получаем указатель на адрес занятой нами памяти.Если проверить `_msize(a)` то соответственно должно выйти `100` как и требовалось.
Но,я часто встречаю в исходниках чего либо следующее `int b=(int)malloc(100)`,то тут уже выходить значение например `93234923`. И что это? это точно такой же адрес памяти? Для чего его приводить в `int`,не понимаю.

Но так же,после явного приведения `(int)` идёт что-то типо `void* C = (void*)((int)b + sizeof(void*))`,тогда это что даёт? то есть мы хотим получить указатель C который равен `93234923` + размер пустого указателя. Зачем? то есть получится `93234923` + (предположим размер указателя) `4 =93234927` и что это вообще такое? откуда такая цифра?

Правильно ли я думаю что это приведение`(int)malloc` даёт нам точно такой же адрес(на запрошенное число `100`) только числовой,и с помощью него мы можем так же выделить к нему дополнительно,допустим мне вдруг нужно не `100`,а `110` то мы к `b` прибавляем `10` (`93234923 + 10=93234933`) и после преобразуем обратно в адрес в котором выделены нужный мне размер памяти `110`? т.е. расширили адрес на `10` больше,только с помощью числового значения.
Или все что я написал бред?

Comment: `это точно такой же адрес памяти? Для чего его приводить в int,не понимаю.` - да, это адрес памяти. Для чего приводить - уточняйте у того, кто писал тот код. Это не имеет никакого смысла. `void* C = (void*)((int)b + sizeof(void*))` - это тоже какой-то г-код, тут идет сдвиг указателя, но для этого не нужно приводить указатель к int, достаточно просто `void * c = b + sizeof(void*);` (при условии что b - это `void *`)

Comment: а на 64битных платформах указанное приведение может быть даже вредным

Comment: `и после преобразуем обратно в адрес в котором выделены нужный мне размер памяти 110?` - никакие манипуляции с указателями не увеличивают размер выделенной через malloc памяти, если запросили 100 байт, то 100 байт так и остается доступно.

Comment: ну я бы  не был столь категоричен. По сути своей, malloc тоже "манипулирует указателями":)

Comment: вот поменял @αλεχολυτ с++ на с и PS моем ответе выглядит криво. Хотя, я думаю, автор все таки с++ тоже интересуется.

Comment: @KoVadim не,все отлично. Вы ответили на многие вопросы,даже которые ещё не задавал)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc(100)` выделяет от 100 байт под Ваши нужды (да, там может быть выделено и 200, но это личное дело менеджера памяти). Обычно, после этого память приводят к удобному указателю, например, к `int*`

```
int* m = (int*)malloc(100);
```

(в си память можно не приводить явно, там чуточку другие правила и там можно писать так `int* m = malloc(100);`).

В результате будет память под массив с 25 элементов типа int. (`sizeof(int)` обычно равен 4 на большинстве платформ, с которыми Вы столкнётесь. Хотя на Arduino Uno (ATMega) `int` имеет размер 2 байта... Так что там будет массив на 50 элементов.

А вот конструкция вида

```
 int b=(int)malloc(100)
```

это уже игра с огнем. Дело в том, что на 64битных платформах (Intel x64) указатель имеет размер 8 байт, а `int` - 4 байта и с таким приведением часть адреса будет утеряна. И дальше такое число разве что для вывода подойдет. Но на платформах, где `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)` - все будет как бы работать.

Теперь посмотрим на это

```
void* C = (void*)((int)b + sizeof(void*))
```

А вот теперь оно начинает прояснятся. Для указателей работает адресная арифметика. И если есть такое

```
int* a = .....;
a+=1;
```

то на самом деле адрес, записанный в a увеличится на на единицу, а на `sizeof(int)`.

Но вот с `void*` история другая. Дело в том, что `sizeof(void)` не определен и арифметика указателей не работает. И в примере выше как раз похоже (да, именно похоже) попытались сделать арифметику указателей "вручную". Зачем? а кто его знает, нужно смотреть в код. Но он точно будет работать только там, где `sizeof(int)>=sizeof(int*)`.

> Правильно ли я думаю что это приведение(int)malloc даёт нам точно такой же адрес(на запрошенное число 100) только числовой,

на некоторых платфомармах это может быть в натяжку сказано.

> и с помощью него мы можем так же выделить к нему дополнительно,допустим мне вдруг нужно не 100,а 110 то мы к b прибавляем 10 (93234923 + 10=93234933) и после преобразуем обратно в адрес в котором выделены нужный мне размер памяти 110?

нет, это так не работает. Арифметика указателей не позволяет выделить больше памяти. Это просто "индексация памяти". Добавляя какое-то число, просто получаете адрес следующей ячейки памяти. И если выйдете за пределы выделенной памяти, то может быть плохо.

Но если нужно больше памяти, можно просто сделать `realloc`.

P.S. `malloc` - это сишные функции. И применять просто так их в плюсах не стоит. Есть `new`/`new[]`

Comment: Для чего нужно приводить указатель к удобному адресу в данном случает (int),разве будет разница 9222232 или F0f234 ? Т.е. зачем это нужно если по сути изменить размер с помощью (int) значения нельзя.
"сделать арифметику указателей "вручную". Зачем? а кто его знает," и что бы это дало? Просто сместили адрес,ок,разве в этом есть выгода?
Я почти  везде что видел/читал было написанно что new обёртка для malloc или я в этом не прав?

Comment: почитайте внимательно, что такое арифметика указателей. Собственно на ней и базируется работа с массивами. И все эти "манипуляции", это просто индексация массива. "сделать арифметику указателей "вручную". Зачем?" - потому что void.  Да, можно сказать, что new это умная обертка вокруг malloc, но new не обязан вызывать malloc