# Мусолю malloc и учусь по исходниках нонейм кода

Tags: c++, c, malloc

Много текста,непонимающий пенёк(я) и чужой код.

Задавал [Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269501/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-intmalloc?noredirect=1#comment2233904_1269501),но по отдельным моментам,код который я нарыл из-за чего появилось много вопросов:

```
// Memory Management
void *(*_internal_hook_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;
// allocate aligned memory
void *internal_align_malloc(size_t size, size_t n) {
    size_t need = size + n + sizeof(void*);
    char *ptr = NULL;
    char *dst;
    if (_internal_hook_malloc) {
        ptr = (char*)_internal_hook_malloc(need);
    }   else {
        ptr = (char*)malloc(need);
    }
    if (ptr == NULL) return NULL;
    dst = (char*)(((size_t)ptr + sizeof(void*) + n - 1) & (~(n - 1)));
    *(char**)(dst - sizeof(char*)) = ptr;
    return dst;
}
```

Поправьте если я ошибаюсь.

`void *(*_internal_hook_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;` Вспомогательная функция для хранения памяти, не сина понимаю значения `*(*` адрес в адресе? видимо так,но зачем такая сложность?

`void *internal_align_malloc(size_t size, size_t n)` Указатель на функцию выравнивания памяти `size`-размер, `n` значение по которому выравниваем.

`size_t need = size + n + sizeof(void*);char *ptr = NULL;char *dst;`- Тут всё ясно

`if (_internal_hook_malloc) {ptr = (char*)_internal_hook_malloc(need);}` -Если  у нас в вспомогательной функции не пусто,то мы берём тот адрес который в ней.

`else {ptr = (char*)malloc(need);}` - Иначе выделяем память.

`if (ptr == NULL) return NULL;` проверка выделения памяти как советуют в одной из статей microsoft

`dst = (char*)(((size_t)ptr + sizeof(void*) + n - 1) & (~(n - 1))); *(char**)(dst - sizeof(char*)) = ptr;` -Вот тут у меня уже затык. `((x+n - 1) & (~(n - 1))` с выравниванием все понятно. Опустим Си стиль с приведением `(char*)` хотя мне тоже не ясно,почему нельзя использовать просто `(void*)`.
Мне уже объяснили что это `(size_t)ptr + sizeof(void*)` арифметика указателей и предположим что я её понял что значение: `(size_t)ptr`=9999231 + `sizeof(void*)`=4 и всё это равно 999923`5`(причем это значение выравненное по n)  если сведения на метаните верны,то он гласит:

> После изменения адреса мы можем получить значение, которое находится по новому адресу, однако это значение может быть неопределенным

То есть в `dst`  я получаю неопределённо значение раз циферка 7ми значная,в общем тут я чайник и дальше я в ступоре.
 `*(char**)(dst - sizeof(char*)) = ptr;` Меня это вводит в заблуждение. `*(char**)` что это за приведение? Что это даёт,кек.  почему `(dst - sizeof(char*)) = ptr;` такой порядок.

И в итоге что? Типо мы выделили память,нам дали ссылку,мы решили её ещё и выровнять добавив от балды `sizeof(void*)` к ней,что бы получить за счет арифметики указателей новую идеальную ссылку для всего. А после я в ступоре  `(dst - sizeof(char*))` вычитаем размер указателя,так он на все типы одинакого размера,почему тут `char` а там `void` и вообще зачем сначала добавлять размер указателя,а потом тот же самый размер вычитать?

И что это вообще такое  `*(char**)`

Ps Не знал про спиральное правило,эта часть отметается,тут тогда всё ясно) Спасибо за подсказку @user7860670 !

> `void *(*_internal_hook_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;` Вспомогательная функция для хранения памяти, не сина понимаю значения `*(*` адрес в адресе? видимо так,но зачем такая сложность?

Comment: `void *(*_internal_hook_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;` - это указатель на функцию, а `void *internal_align_malloc(size_t size, size_t n)` - сама функция, а не указатель. А  `*(*` там вылезает, так как это говнокод и в С/C++ объявлению разбираются по *спиральному правилу* (т.е. начиная с середины, потом последовательно влево и вправо).

Comment: @user7860670 ,не знал про это правило,спасибо!

Comment: @nick_n_a ,` с выравниванием все понятно.` я же писал,даже скажу больше что выравнивание вверх до ближайшего большего числа кратного n.

Comment: видимо на целевой платформе malloc может вернуть не выравненный адрес, а обращение по не выравненному адресу приводит к исключение на процессоре (типично для arm)

Comment: Ну тогда становится всё понятным, функция резервирует больше памяти чем надо что бы хватило на запомнить старый адрес и выровнять. Сохраняет старый адрес вверху, делает выравнивание, и вернёт выровняный адрес.

Comment: @nick_n_a погоди ка. То есть,судя по коду он сохраняет адрес на выделенную память только в случае если указатель на функцию не пустой и в ней он сохранён. Но тут,для этого 2ая переменная dst которая модифицирует адрес. Ток я не понимаю,у нас есть выделенный адрес,но мы пытаемся его расширить выравнивая в большую сторону кратно какому-то числу? То есть по сути новый адрес с новоой расширенной памятью(переместили на другой адрес) было 100 байт выделено стало 110 в другой  адресе? или что._. Мне писали так незя._.

Comment: @nick_n_a Сори что пенёк и не не соображаю х)  Так там есть код ` ptr = (char*)malloc(need); ` если до этого выровнять число то тут вопросов нету. Выровнял,выделил. Но тут же сначала выделил,потом начал выравнивать. Хорошо,это я понял что нужно нужно 8 на дополнительные расходы,но до меня не доходит что после выделения идёт,не понимаю.  Типо мы сдвигаем адрес,что бы получить дополнительно 8 байт?

Comment: @nick_n_a предположим у нас есть адрес выделенной памяти 0000101,нам нужно выровнять и для этого просто делаем сдвиг, что бы адрес был не 0000101 ,а 0000104. То есть по сути он как был адресом 0000101 так и остался(выделанная память), но адрес 0000104 содержит наш 0000101 выделенной и +3 (просто 3 пустых ячейки для использования обслуживания,что бы последовательно никто не занял кроме нашей выделенной памяти). Теперь так понял? Х)

Comment: Да, правильно..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут имеет место выравнивание памяти. Выравнивание - всегда перерасход памяти, но оно нужно для того, что бы эффективно использовался кеш. Кроме того, некоторые системы, не умеют корректно делать обращение, если двойное слово находится на двух страницах памяти одновременно - это вызывает исключение. Исключение может быть обработано дополнительной программой которая этот конфликт разрешает - но такое обращение существенно замедляет программу. Для того что бы программа не замедлялась - используется выравнивание.

```
// allocate aligned memory
void *internal_align_malloc(size_t size, size_t n)
```

Тут size - это размер блока, который получит вызвавшая программа. n - размер выравнивания.

Покажу выравнивание на 4.

```
Адрес  Нужный адрес  Итог             addr  + n - 1) & (~(n - 1))   x100  Выделено
0       0 или 4       4 или 8 байт     4                             104   (4)8
1       4..7          5 байт            4                            101   7
2       4..7          6 байт            4                            102   6
3       4..7          7 байт            4                            103   5
```

Так как между 7 и 8 разница не большая, то случай с 0 (итог 4) как правило не используют, потому что алгоритм усложняется. Применяют более простой вариант 4 (итог 8). Итог - означает, сколько надо байт что бы сохранить 4-байтное выровняное значение.

Получается, что если у нас выравнивание 4 байта, то для 4 байт понадобится размер от 4 до 8 байт. Но так на выходе мы получим адрес, и зараннее мы не знаем какой размер у нас будет, то мы берём по максимуму с запасом. Т.е. мы просим 8 байт - после обработки останется 4, а 4 пойдут на "накладные расходы". Хоть и на самом деле первая программа получила больше байт, это во внимание не берётся. Считается что программа получила столько сколько запросила, вызвав функцию. Больше отдать можно (хоть это не правильно теоретически, но практически байт в байт не выйдет), меньше нет.

Теперь смотрим для 100 байт. Для 100 байт нам понадобится от 101 до 104 байт. Аналогично что бы выравнять 100 байт по границам 4 байта - нам нужно 104 байта.

Ещё 4 байта тратится что бы хранить адрес, который вернула вложенная malloc, для того что бы сделать free. Итого у нас `need = 100 + 4 + 4 = 108`. Функцию free тоже надо будет вызвать через "обвертку", то что вернёт  internal_align_malloc - этому результату free делать нежелательно (не все менеджеры памяти умеют определять выделеный кусок по середине интервала, принято что тот адрес который вернул malloc нужно передать в free.

Не смотря на то, что зачастую выделается больше чем надо, не рекомендуется использовать больше, если нету функции (что бы получить "capacity" принято называть это свойство), которая отдаст реальный размер памяти для выделеного участка. т.е. если выделено 100 - надо использовать 100, а не 101, или 102. Если пытаться записать больше - можно случайно "разрушить память" - и программа слетит или будет некорректно работать.

Если надо больше памяти (расширить память) - есть два алгоритма а)выделить новый устасток памяти, и перекопировать в него старый, старый участок -освободить. б) вызвать "relloc" "realloc" если такая функция доступна. (по сути relloc делает первое).

Теоретически - байтовый "остаток" использовать можно, но на практике это делают редко, поскольку если участок освобождается, то "остаток" - анулируется. Но бывают "пулы", это когда делается malloc, а free - никогда (память освобождается по завершению программы). Но боюсь что на хранение каждого одного "свободного" байта понадобится минимум 4 байта информации, который можно запаковать, но эти операции будут довольно сложны, поэтому "остаток" как правило не используется. Если у вас самописный relloc, то есть смысл учитывать остаток в хвосте, и если запросят разширить память на величину остатка и менее - то можно вернуть тот же участок.

Теперь, как записывается адрес в участок. Допустим вам дали адрес 4.

Тогда после преобразований у вас адрес dst  равен 8.
Тогда dst - sizeof(char*) = адрес 4.

---

Про `char**`. Преобразование указателей.

Допустим addr = 4. Что бы по адресу 4 записать число int, надо перевести адрес в тип указателя на int, и раскрыть указатель через * (оператор звёздочка) что бы записать туда значение, допусти 1. Т.е. `(int*)addr` - это указатель на адрес, который можно раскрыть как int, тогда 1 туда можно записать так `*(int*)addr = 1` или так `((int*)addr)[0] = 1`.

Теперь, мы хотим записать указатель `char *ptr` (пемеменную ptr). Он имеет тип `char*`. Что бы записать по адресу значение ptr нужно привести адрес к указателю на тип `char*`, т.е. `(char**)addr`. Итого присвоение можно сделать так `*(char**)(addr)=ptr`. Теперь вместо addr подставляем выражение  `dst - sizeof(char*)` и получаем `*(char**)(dst - sizeof(char*)) = ptr`.

Comment: Окей,спасибо большое! С этим моментом я разобрался. Только единственное что не понятно что с приведением `*(char**)` ,что это за указатель указателей указателя х)

Comment: Я дополнил, там много обьяснять для коментария.

Comment: Сложна. Перечитаю пару раз мб дойдёт. Спасибо большое что помог!

Comment: `void *(*_internal_hook_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;` тут другой случай. `void*` - тип возвращаемой ф-ции, (*_internal_hook_malloc) - означает, что это не функция, а переменная, указатель которой указывает на функцию, которая возвращает `void*` который до скобки, и имеет параметры, которые в следующих скобках, т.е. `size_t size`. `= NULL` - что бы в переменной _internal_hook_malloc не было мусора, записываем NULL т.е. пустая ссылка.